# How do I vectorize this expression with Python numpy?

Tags: python, numpy

Given numpy arrays P(N), D(N, N), I want to compute array A(N):

```
A_i = SUM(P_i - P_j) where j is such that D[i][j] is True
A_i = 0 otherwise
```

So,

```
A_i = N*P_i - (P_m + P_n+...) where D[i][m], D[i][n],... are all True
```

I could write the above using a double loop and enumerate(), but it is quite slow. Just wondering how I can write this in terms of numpy ufuncs.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If I've understood the question right, here's one way to do it.

```
A = P*D.sum(axis=1)-D.dot(P)
```

Comment: +1 but I think it is `P * len(P)`, not `P * D.sum(axis=1)`. Other than that, beautiful use of matrix multiplication.

Comment: @Jaime: the original poster meant that N = number of k for which D[i][k] is true, so N ≠ `len(P)` (this can be seen in the first formula), and IanH is correct.

Comment: @EOL That's not what I understand from "Given numpy arrays P(N), D(N, N)..." but I guess only the OP will know.

Comment: @Jaime: Good point, the parts we quoted from the question are inconsistent. In any case, between the current answer by IanH and your comment, the question is answered. :)

Comment: Yes, the question is ambiguous, but you're right, either way, it's answered.

Comment: Wow, thanks @IanH. I shouldn't have written N*P_i - it's M*P_i where M is as in above answer.

Comment: Yah, no problem. Good luck with it!